# dgrid - not able to keep selection mode as "single" when using a Dojo Memory/ObjectStore as store

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I m not able to keep the selectionMode as "single" or "extended".
Only multiple selection of rows is happening, when I m using a dojo Memory/ ObjectStore as store.

```
    require([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/request",
    "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
    "dojo/store/Memory",
    "dgrid/OnDemandGrid",
    "dgrid/Keyboard",
    "dgrid/Selection",
    "dojo/DeferredList",
    "dojo/domReady!"
    ],
    function (declare, request, ObjectStore, Memory, OnDemandGrid, Keyboard, Selection, DeferredList) {

        var ddstore;


        claimDef = dojo.xhrGet({
            url: "pageToGetData.aspx",
            handleAs: "json",
            load: function (res) {
                // Resolve when content is received 
                ddstore = new Memory({ data: res });

            }
        });


        var defs = new dojo.DeferredList([claimDef]);
        defs.then(function (results) {
            // Create a new constructor by mixing in the components
            var CustomGrid = declare([OnDemandGrid, Keyboard, Selection]);

            claimAccountsGrid = new CustomGrid({
                columns: [
                { label: "Label1", field: "Field1" },
                { label: "Label2", field: "Field2" },
                { label: "Label3", field: "Field3" },
             ]

            }, "claimAccountsGrid");
            claimAccountsGrid.setStore(ddstore);


        });
    });
```

But, when I m hard-coding the same data that is obtained from that page, I m able to get the default selectionMode as "extended".(This way):

```
    require([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/request",
    "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
    "dojo/store/Memory",
    "dgrid/OnDemandGrid",
    "dgrid/Keyboard",
    "dgrid/Selection",
    "dojo/DeferredList",
    "dojo/domReady!"
    ],
    function (declare, request, ObjectStore, Memory, OnDemandGrid, Keyboard, Selection, DeferredList) {
        pageNo = 1;
        var ddstore;


        claimDef = dojo.xhrGet({
            url: "pageToGetData.aspx",
            handleAs: "json",
            load: function (res) {
                // Resolve when content is received 
                ddstore = //new Memory({ data: res });

                [
                { "Field1": "value1", "Field2": null, "Field3": "1" },
                { "Field1": "value2", "Field2": null, "Field3": "1"}
                ];
            }
        });


        var defs = new dojo.DeferredList([claimDef]);
        defs.then(function (results) {
            // Create a new constructor by mixing in the components
            var CustomGrid = declare([OnDemandGrid, Keyboard, Selection]);

            claimAccountsGrid = new CustomGrid({
                columns: [
                { label: "Label1", field: "Field1" },
                { label: "Label2", field: "Field2" },
                { label: "Label3", field: "Field3" },
             ]
            }, "claimAccountsGrid");
            //claimAccountsGrid.setStore(ddstore);
            claimAccountsGrid.renderArray(ddstore);

        });
    });
```

Comment: Try this `ddstore = new Observable(new Memory({ data: res }));` for this you need to require it as `dojo/store/Observable`. I hope it work for you Good Luck!.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, using dojo/store/Observable didn't work as well.

Comment: Inside dgrid folder there is test folder checkout this folder may be you get any example to find any helpful solution.

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't shown the actual data I can't be 100% certain, but this is something that happens if you fail to properly ensure your items have unique identifiers (or, if the identifier field is something other than `id`, you forgot to set `idProperty` on the Memory store to inform it of what field to look at).

See also https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/issues/61